# Combine variables that are extremely lightly populated?

Tags: data-mining, data-transformation

A similar question to my other question about mixed distributions.
Here i have quite a few variables that are populated to less than 5%, many are even populated to less than 1%
this 1% would represent 10 of 1000 entries

If i was designing a survey for example these groups are too 'fine' in their detail

These again are a collection of almost OR events (If variable 1 and 2 are populated 3 - 10 will be zeros)
In the real world these are loosely 'types' of food eaten. So they all have a loose link
they are important as 'weight'is an output

My issue is that combining them all together would loose a lot of information but leaving them separate would seem to include both too many variables with any one not having any descriptive power.

Is some form of combination my only real option? Ie, external information saying input variable 1,2,3 can be combined and 4, 5, 6 are similar enough to be combined. This may or may not be possible as there may not be any links like this